# 2D histogram of angles between vectors and a fixed vector

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, angle

I am looking at the orientation of molecules with respect to an interface as a function of their distance from the interface. The molecules are approximately linear, so I measure the angle theta between a linear vector from one atom to another, and the interface normal. I do this using the dot product. I then plot a 2d histogram of the count of each angle, with cos(θ) on the y-axis and the distance from the interface on the x-axis. I have checked that my code correctly calculates the angles many times and it does. However, in my 2D histograms there is a stripe of increased density of cos(θ)=0. The stripe is very uniform (no gradient from 0, just a stripe) and I get it in every system (see image below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE849.png)). Here is a snippet of my code:

''' def unit_vectors(vectors): norms = np.linalg.norm(vectors, axis=2)
return vectors / np.expand_dims(norms, axis=2)

def calculate_angles(vectors): dot_products = np.sum(unit_vectors(vectors) * reference, axis=2) return dot_products '''

At first, I thought this was a symmetry artifact in measuring angles between 0 and 180. Almost as if the molecules at 90 are being 'overrepresented' since they are being plotted only in one place, while molecules at 45 and 135, for example, are at the same orientation but are being plotted in two separate regions of the plot (depending on the arbitrary vector direction). This would make sense, as I see roughly double the number of molecules at 90 degrees throughout the system compared with all other angles. However, the 'stripe' has a thickness of about cos(θ)=-0.04 to cos(θ)=0.04, so now I am unsure?

I am aware of the uniform random orientation in space is distributed according to sin(θ) of angles between two 3D vectors as discussed in Angular probability distribution between 3D vectors?. This problem seems distinct from that due to the sharp preference at 90. The problem doesn't go away when I normalise by sin(θ).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: find a vector that falls in the bad bin and see what it looks like. Also, use the formatting to get your code to be readable.

Comment: "molecules are approximately linear" , "linear vector from one atom to another". Is there a bias in the choice of which pair of atoms of the molecule you are measuring? If two sections of the molecule have an angle of 177.5 degrees between them, and you always choose the section that is closest to 90 degrees from the interface, then you will get a band that is 2.5 degrees wide. Basically in that band you would get double the number of occurrences because it is essentially an overlap between the range above and the range below 90.

Comment: Hi Jaap, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by two sections of the molecule? The centre of the molecule contains an 'S-N-S' group with a bond angle of ~119 degrees, which is fixed. The vector is defined as from one S atom to the other in each molecule.

Comment: So there are exactly two S-atoms, and it is always those two atoms that define the orientation of the molecule? If so, then I was barking up the wrong tree. I thought that maybe the orientation of a molecule was not defined quite so well because you were not always guaranteed to be using the same two atoms.

Comment: Since you are saying that there are double the number of measurements in the band around 90, I still suspect that your histogram is was created by adding two separate histograms, one for the set of positive $\cos$ measurements, one for negative ones, and that somehow they unexpectedly overlap. There is some noise or other effect that causes both sets to bleed over the line by about 2.5 degrees and create a doubly thick band.